# AGI command and php file in Asterisk

Tags: php, voip, asterisk, agi

I want to make simple IVR using php in Asterisk. when i run php program individually , it works without any problem. but when i call it by AGI command in the Asterisk it does not works.
this is my php file :

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
 set_time_limit(30);
 require('phpagi.php');
 $agi = new AGI();
 $agi->answer();
 $file = '/var/www/html/test.txt';
 $current = file_get_contents($file);
 $current .= "Test\n";
 file_put_contents($file, $current);
 $agi->say_digits(1234);
 $agi->hangup();
 ?>
```

and this is Dialplan :

```
[testphp]
exten => 6565,1,Answer 
exten => 6565 2,Playback(Hello-World)
exten => 6565,3,AGI(testphp.php) 
exten => 6565 4,Playback(Hello-World)
exten => 6565,5,Hangup
```

when i call 6565 by my phone , it only plays twice "Hello World" message!
php file permission is excutable.

I have installed Elastix(Asterisk) in VirtualBox.

What am I doing wrong?

please help.

Comment: did u see on the CLI if its generating any error ? The best way to debug an AGI to put the features step by step. say you first test if it executes 'say_digit'... !!

Comment: also check the location of the PHP script you have created.

Comment: php script location is : `/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/`. but how to debug or test AGI and say_digit?

Comment: first do nothin in AGI except echoing some output(verbose), so you can have an idea that the script is running and executing and gradually add your other things.

Comment: could you do "set core verbose 99" in the asterisk cli, then run your agi application (by issuing a call) and capture and post the console output here?

Comment: `set agi debug on` will give you debugging for your agi script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do follwoing:

1) stop asterisk

```
asterisk -rx "core stop now"
```

2) start it in ssh console

```
asterisk -vvvgc
```

3) enable asterisk AGI debug

```
agi set debug on
```

you will see error in your script. also check that selinux is off